# How to get Facebook-Feeds in Trillian without connecting to Facebook-Chat?

Tags: chat, facebook, newsreader, feed, trillian

I installed the **trial** of **Trillian** ***5.0*** Build 22 (I don't know if the version 4 Astra is any different).
I successfully added my Facebook account so I can see my facebook news on Trillian and works great.

The problem is that **I don't want to use the Facebook-chat**, and ***if I disconnect the Facebook-chat*** the rest of **the facebook stuff** (news, events, groups, request) **also disappears**.

I tried by setting the Facebook status to **`Away`**; and I'm not sure if someone can chat with me if I choose that; but anyway I still have the contacts list full of people I don't want.

**EDIT:** Maybe I wasn't clear enough about the Facebook part. And that might be why some people fell this is off-topic. But when I talk about Facebook in this question, I'm not referring to the Facebook site at any point. I'm mean the **Facebook plugin of Trillian** (and it's not an user plugin; it's a built-in plugin).

Comment: After reading the FAQ, checking other StackExchange sites, and reading the page of the moderator who closed this question (@random), I still cannot understand why this question is off-topic :(. This question is about the use of the software Trillian. There are 4 more questions on SU about Trillian why is this one off-topic?

Comment: Closed on the account of it being heavily reliant/context for Facebook, which is off-topic. Reopened, but if other users feel that this is primarily an FB question, they're open to closing.